# imagex /apply - How can I tell when it's done? Or what it is doing?

Tags: imagex

I made an image with ICE (image configuration editor), installed it, loaded some programs, and finally I captured the image which was 1.3GB. Then I booted a different machine with windows PE and ran imagex /apply, and applied the image to the c:\ drive. At one point, it showed 2 hours left, and I could watch the status as the time changed. Now its just sitting there without any visible progress. It doesn't seem to be done because it didn't go back to the command prompt. Just a cursor blinking, nothing else.

I also ran the /verify switch too.

So has anyone ever run this imagex /apply /verify commands before? Is this normal behavior? Am I really waiting for something at this point or should I do a hard reset and take my chances?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given that it took 2 hours to deploy this image, I'd say your source media is fairly slow (Is it a USB Drive? A network share?) The /verify option does exactly what it sounds like, and verifies the write operation succeeded by comparing it to the source image. You will nearly double your imaging time by doing this.

Also note, that if you accidentally enter into a Select text operation (right click mouse) in the Windows PE command prompt window, the entire ImageX operation will also pause waiting for you to copy/paste text. I've done this myself once or twice by simply bumping my mouse accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I had unplugged my USB keyboard and switched it to another machine. Then I pressed enter and surprise! suddenly it says [20%] applying (with verification) progress: 2:47:39 hrs remaining.

So not real sure what that means. But sounds like the system or some component of it feel asleeep and was waiting for me to press a key. hope that doesn't happen again. DOH!

Comment: A little more detail in case some one runs this. It took me 14 minutes to capture the image and was taking hours to apply. Not ever seeing imagex apply done before, I had no idea this was wrong. Turned out what I was doing was not installing to hte kiosk hard drive, but to a USB key (DOH!). So it took forever then ran out of space. Now I pointed it at the correct drive and it applied in about 2 minutes. So thats the rough time involved for 1.3 GB image. Hope that helps.